# Plotting multiple countplots via a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with different columns, one being `year` and another being `doy`. I would like to loop over the years (2001 to 2019) and plot the `doy` in different seaborn countplots for each year.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
print(df.head())

        ID  doy    Year  ...  NA_L1NAME  B_year        number
1772  1774  199    2001  ...        1.1  1934.0  7.942371e+06
1786  1788  160    2002  ...        1.1  1953.0  2.146587e+05
1792  1794  199    2003  ...        1.2  1960.0  2.017792e+07
1801  1803  199    2004  ...        1.3  1968.0  4.293173e+05
1802  1804  195    2005  ...        1.4  1969.0  1.824599e+07

f, axes = plt.subplots(4,5)
for f,ax in zip(AKB.Year, axes.ravel()):
    sns.countplot(AKB.doy, ax = ax)
    ax.set_title(f)
```

However, this does not work.

How can I do it?

Comment: maybe you want a facet grid https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sns.catplot` with `kind='count'` to create a FacetGrid of countplots:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2021)
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.repeat(np.arange(2001, 2020), 100)})
df['doi'] = np.random.randint(180, 200, len(df))

sns.catplot(data=df, kind='count', x='doi', col='year', col_wrap=5,
            height=3, aspect=1.8)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot with kind='count']